# Circos heatmap how to split by labels?

Tags: r, heatmap, circlize, circos

I can't split with [circle heatmap with external labels but not spliting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNpaD.png) circos.heatmap

```
library(circlize)

colores1 = colorRamp2(c(0,0.5,1,2,3,4), c("lightblue1","Orchid1","Orchid4","maroon2","maroon4", "red4"))

circos.heatmap(transpuesta_metano_unified, col = colores1, rownames.side = "outside", cluster = FALSE)
```

I need to split by label of the image. Any help?

Comment: I cannot tell from reading this whether `transpuesta_metano_unified` is somthing that is in the package `circulize`, but I'm guessing it is not. So if my guess is correct then you are not asking a question with a [MCVE]. Such questions get closed unless someone comes along on a weekend (unlikely) and knows the answer off the top of their head. For the rest of us adventurous readers who are amused to try new packages and functions, .... we need an R data object to play with. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example